# Recurrence Relations-For n∈\N0 let w(n) denote the number of 1s in the binary representation of n. For example, w(9) = 2

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, self-learning, closed-form

For $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ let $w(n)$ denote the number of $1$s in the binary representation of $n$. For example, $w(9) = 2$, since $9$ is $1001$ in binary. Try to find a closed formula for $g(n)$ in terms of $n$ and $w(n)$. If you succeed, the following question will be very easy.  Let $n = 10000000000000011$ in binary notation. What is $g(n)$? Write your answer in binary!

Here $g(n):=f(n!)$
Please Help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: You have defined $w(n)$ but what are $f(n)$ and $g(n)$? $g$ seems to be defined in terms of $f$ - or is $f$ supposed to be $w$? Note also that your question does not indicate where the idea or recurrence relations for this problem comes from. If you give a bit more context you may clarify some things in your own mind - you will certainly make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I did I found that g(n)= (n/2) + g(n/2) and it works correctly